# Implement back navigation with DrawerLayout and AppCompatActivity without DrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-appcompat

I've been searching and thinking how to implement the desire behaviour that I want when switching back and forth between fragments when using a Navigation Drawer. Actually the documentation says: 
***When using fragments in your app, individual FragmentTransaction objects may represent context changes that should be added to the back stack. For example, if you are implementing a master/detail flow on a handset by swapping out fragments, you should ensure that pressing the Back button on a detail screen returns the user to the master screen***

So in my app I have a MainActivity that controls everything and a navigation layout within you can change between predefined options. This is the view when you launch the app

[image]

When you click on an item in the navigation drawer it opens a new fragment that replaces the main_content as follows:

[image]

At this point the behaviour is the correct one, so if you want to change the options you need to open the navigation drawer again to toggle between the menu options.

This is the Main Activity (notice that there is no Drawer Toggle)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSnackBarView = findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout);

        setToolbar(); // Set Toolbar como action bar


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        drawerTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(drawerTitle, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        }

    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            // Poner ícono del drawer toggle
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(final NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // Marcar item presionado
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        // Crear nuevo fragmento
                        String title = menuItem.getTitle().toString();
                        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                        selectItem(title, id);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectItem(String title, int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(PlaceholderFragment.ARG_SECTION_TITLE, title);

        Fragment fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                .commit();


        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_localizacion:
                //Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_localization, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                LocalizacionFragment fragment_localizacion = new LocalizacionFragment();
//                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_localization, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment_localizacion)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_productos:
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_productos, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_consejos:
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_consejos, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 3;
                ConsejosFragment fragment_consejo = new ConsejosFragment();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment_consejo)
                        .commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        drawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // Cerrar drawer

        setTitle(title); // título actual

    }

}
```

I don't use the hamburger icon because it hides under the Navigation Layout, but here is the thing. When you click on "Recetas" in the recycle view it open a new fragment (replace) but now I want to show the up caret icon and give proper back navigation to my app.

Here is the code of the "Consejos" fragment class

**Consejos.java**

```
public class ConsejosFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecycler;
    ConsejosAdapter mAdapter;
    FragmentActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.mActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        List items = new ArrayList();
        items.add(new ConsejosInfo("Recetas", R.drawable.icon_recetas));


        /* Inflamos el layout */
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.consejos_layout_recycler, container, false);
        /* Obtenemos el Recycle */
        mRecycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_consejos);

        /* Creamos el adaptador */
        mAdapter = new ConsejosAdapter(mActivity, items);

        /* Set click en adapter */


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

And this is the adapter that the Recyclerview use and handles the click on the item inside:

**Adapter.java**

```
public class ConsejosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConsejosAdapter.ConsejosViewHolder> {

    private List<ConsejosInfo> _items = new ArrayList<ConsejosInfo>();
    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private Context context;

    public ConsejosAdapter(FragmentActivity mActivity, List<ConsejosInfo> items) {
        this._items = items;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ConsejosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_consejos, viewGroup, false);
        return new ConsejosViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ConsejosViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(_items.get(position).get_imagen());
        viewHolder.nombre.setText(_items.get(position).get_nombre());
    }

    public class ConsejosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView imagen;
        public TextView nombre;

        public ConsejosViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.consejos_imagen);
            nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.consejos_nombre);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RecetasFragment recetasFragment = new RecetasFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, recetasFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        }
    }
}
```

In the Consejos Adapter I added to backstack the fragment before calling the new fragment (inside fragment) and that changes the behaviour of the back button, so before this if you press the back button is closes the app but now it takes you to the Consejos fragment, but now I want to add the up caret and make the exactly same operation as when you click the back button but I don't know how to achieve it.

Please feel free to ask for more code

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the full answer:
We will use the interfaces to communicate with the `MainActivity` from `RecetasFragment` so we can enable and disable navigation back button.
`RecetasFragment` class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by hema on 8/19/2015.
 */
public class RecetasFragment extends Fragment {

    private CommunicateWithActivity mWithActivity;

    public RecetasFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);


        try {

            mWithActivity = (CommunicateWithActivity) activity; // MainActivity must implement CommunicateWithActivity interface.

            mWithActivity.enableNavigationBack(true); // We enable navigation back here.

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement CommunicateWithActivity");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recetas, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mWithActivity.enableNavigationBack(false); // We disable navigation back here, restore menu icon.

    }

    public interface CommunicateWithActivity {

        void enableNavigationBack(boolean enable);// we will implement this method in MainActivity class.

    }

}
```

And in `MainActivity` class we will implement `CommunicateWithActivity` interface, Modify your `MainActivity` class (only required modifications):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecetasFragment.CommunicateWithActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        mSnackBarView = findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        drawerTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(drawerTitle, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        }

    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(final NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // Marcar item presionado
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        // Crear nuevo fragmento
                        String title = menuItem.getTitle().toString();
                        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                        selectItem(title, id);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectItem(String title, int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(PlaceholderFragment.ARG_SECTION_TITLE, title);

        Fragment fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                .commit();


        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_localizacion:
                //Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_localization, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                LocalizacionFragment fragment_localizacion = new LocalizacionFragment();
//                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_localization, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment_localizacion)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_productos:
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_productos, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_consejos:
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_consejos, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 3;
                ConsejosFragment fragment_consejo = new ConsejosFragment();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment_consejo)
                        .commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        drawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // Cerrar drawer

        setTitle(title); // título actual

    }

    @Override
    public void enableNavigationBack(boolean enable) {

        if(enable) {

            // We enable the navigation back button here

            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // On navigation back button clicked.

                    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) { // Check if there is fragments in BackStack.

                        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // PopBackStack.

                    } else {

                        // You can implement this part as you want.

                        return;

                    }

                }
            });

        } else {

            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);

            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     if(drawerLayout != null) {
                         drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                     }
                 }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: Hello @hema18 I've trying to implement your suggested answer but I need to implement the interface in MainActivity but I dont know exactly how to do it, the enableNavigationBack function it is defined in the MainActivity class so it cant be a function of the interface.. and also I don't know why you do this: 
`if(savedInstanceState == null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment(),
                    MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName()).commit();

        }`

Comment: hello, @hema18 I'm still stuck on that, could you please help me? thank you so much

Comment: Hi @hema18, sorry for the late answer (I've been dealing with things in collage). I did what you said, and when you click on "recetas" it opens a gridview (in recetas fragment) and the hamburger icon disappears and is substituted by the up caret icon, but whenever you click it doesn't do anything (even the menu doesn't appear) :S

Comment: I managed to do the behaviour I want! (just have to change from Recetas Fragment to RecetasViewFragment) the only thing is that when you return to the gridview of the recetas (perfect) the icon of the up caret disappears and appears again the menu icon, the thing is that is doesn't have a behaviour, if you click on it nothings happens... could you please help me? what am I missing?

Comment: What do you want to do when click on icon?

Comment: Hi @hema18 just wanted to show the drawer again. but in the else method of the enabledNavigationBack(boolean enable) in MainActivity I did this `else {
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            setToolbar();
        }` and now it works fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, I will edit my answer, just change enabledNavigationBack(boolean enable) method

Comment: I edited my answer please modify only enabledNavigationBack(boolean enable)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me @hema18 another thing (sorry for border you, but I understand you maybe don't have time) have you ever implemented the CollapsingToolbarLayout and AppBarLayout along with toolbar?

Comment: Never mind, No i don't but you can check this example https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare